# Why VS IDE gives error when we create private class

Tags: c#, oop

If we create private class under any namespace then we got compilation error but if we create private class as a nested class in another class then it compile fine. Another guy explained why we got an error for declaring private under any namespace ? He said:

> Allowing classes to be private to a namespace would achieve no
>   meaningful level of protection.Any assembly in the world could simply
>   reference your dll, and start writing code in your namespace which
>   accesses your supposedly private classes.I think that's possibly the
>   answer you'd get from Microsoft.

I just really do not understand this sentence `"start writing code in your namespace which accesses your supposedly private classes"`

How can any one access my private class? Any can tell me this `"start writing code in your namespace which accesses your supposedly private classes"`

Comment: `Any assembly in the world could simply reference your dll, and start writing code in your namespace which accesses your supposedly private classes`, ah..I think it is exactly the opposite.

Comment: I guess what you need might be `internal` class and not really `private` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have one DLL where you wrote:

```
// hypotetical code !
namespace My.Namespace
{
    private class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

By this you *want* to declare that this class can only be used withing the namespace `My.Namespace`. You want to make this class internal to that namespace and protect if form usage outside.

Now anyone could create a different DLL reference the above DLL and declare the same namespace `My.Namespace` and actually be able to use `MyClass` anyway. Because its in the same namespace:

```
// hypotetical code !
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        private hisClass = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

What use is the private modifier in this case?

Comment: how one can create instance of my private class like private hisClass = new MyClass(); ?? can u explain in bit detail. thanks

Comment: It is not possible! This example only served as a purpose to explain ***why*** it is not possible.

Comment: first of all c# won't allow us to declare a private class. we can declare private class only as a nested class in another class. so now way another person in same namespace can not use my private class....am i right??

Comment: Yes, that nested private class can only be used within the parent class.

Comment: You've got the right answer but it's worth emphasizing this is 'hypothetical code' and it would _not_ give an error in AnotherClass. Consider changing that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following scenario:

You write an assembly `A.dll` with a namespace `Mou.MyStuff`. In that namespace, there is a private class `SomeClass`. To whom should that class be visible, based on its `private` visibility? Only to other types in the same namespace?

Then, someone else can write his or her own assembly `B.dll`. In that assembly, they can define a class `SomeOtherClass` **in namespace `Mou.MyStuff`**. Nothing prevents them from using the **very same** namespace as you did, hence there would be absolutely no obstacle to accessing your "private" type.

If what you are looking for is visibility only within your assembly, use the [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) visibility.

Comment: first of all c# won't allow us to declare a private class. we can declare private class only as a nested class in another class. so now way another person in same namespace can not use my private class....am i right??

Comment: @Mou people are trying to explain the rule by saying "imagine that wasn't the rule, here's what would happen. that's bad, so this is why it's the rule" and you keep responding "but that would never happen because it's the rule!" which is not helping you understand their point